# How to dynamically create Q_Properties

Tags: qt, properties, pyqt, pyside

I want to create `Q_Properties` dynamically from a tuple containing the property names as strings.

The following non_dynamic code works:

```
class MyObject(QObject):
    def __init__(self,startval=42):
        self.ppval = startval

    def readPP(self):
        return self.ppval

    def setPP(self,val):
        self.ppval = val

    pp = QtCore.Property(int, readPP, setPP)
```

My first attempt was to use the `setProperty` function but it returns `False`, meaning the property is not added to the `staticMetaObject` and is therefore not visible to Qt's StyleSheets.

```
class MyObject(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,startval=42):
        self.ppval = startval
        print(self.setProperty('pp', QtCore.Property(int, self.readPP, self.setPP)))

    def readPP(self):
        return self.ppval

    def setPP(self,val):
        self.ppval = val
```

Another approach was to use `setAttr`. but again it fails to add the property to the `staticMetaObject`.

```
class MyObject(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,startval=42):
        self.ppval = startval
        setattr(self, 'pp', QtCore.Property(int, self.readPP, self.setPP)

    def readPP(self):
        return self.ppval

    def setPP(self,val):
        self.ppval = val
```

So far I haven't found a way to add something manually to `staticMetaObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to stick my neck out here and say that I don't think it is possible to do this. The meta-object is created dynamically *during the exceution of the python class statement*, so it is not possible to add anything to it afterwards.

You can try the following after the class is constructed:

```
    MyObject.pp = QtCore.Property(int, MyObject.readPP, MyObject.setPP)
```

and it will function as a normal *python* property:

```
    obj = MyObject()
    print(obj.pp) # prints "42"
```

but it will *not* be listed as a meta-property:

```
    meta = obj.metaObject()
    for index in range(meta.propertyCount()):
        print('meta: %s' % meta.property(index).name())
    # only prints "meta: objectName"
```

The [setProperty](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#setProperty) method is of no use here, because although it can be used to set the values of *existing* meta-properties, any *new* properties created in this way will not themselves become meta-properties. Instead, they will become *dynamic* properties, which can be *read* via qss but not set. Only meta-properties can be [set via qss](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html#setting-qobject-properties).

So it looks like the only way to create meta-properties dynamically would be to create a new class using [type](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). Instances of this new class could then be used as a proxy for gathering information from the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

I came to a similar problem as @BoshWash, with the difference, that I wanted to generate the dict programatically. As a side-effekt I have a proof-of-concept sniped.

@ekhumoro already proposed a solution which is working:

> So it looks like the only way to create meta-properties dynamically
> would be to create a new class using type. Instances of this new class
> could then be used as a proxy for gathering information from the
> stylesheet.

An alternative solution is to add a baseClass to the "dynamic-called" object and do the initialization during `__init_subclass__`

I impemented/tested the approach with metaclasses, and it is actually working.

The trick is, to use the `__prepare__` function in the meta function. One alternative is to use a derived funktion and use the `__init_subclass__` method (I also implemented that one, but it is not as handy as the posted solution). It is important to clear the arguments of the `__new__`, otherwise the Qt-metaclass will fail.

The main magic happens in the line:

```
generatedProperties = { "foo": "FOO", "bar": 1}
    
newType = types.new_class(f"MyObjectDynamic", (MyObject,), {
                "metaclass": Meta, 
                "propertiesDict": generatedProperties
                }, lambda ns: ns)
```

The important point is to have an entry-point bevore the Qt-Meta object will do it's magic.

main_test.py:

```
import pytest

import PySide2.QtCore as QtCore
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

from functools import partial
import types

class Meta(type(QtCore.QObject)):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # needs to be done, type(QObject) needs an empty kwargs, otherwise it is not possible to pass arguments to __prepare__
        kwargs.clear()
        x = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return x
    
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(cls, bases, *args, **kwargs): # No keywords in this case
        newDict = dict()
        if "propertiesDict" not in kwargs:
            return newDict

        propertiesDict = kwargs["propertiesDict"]

        for field in propertiesDict:
            propertyType = type(propertiesDict[field])

            s = QtCore.Signal()
            newDict[f"{field}Changed"] = s
            newDict[f"{field}Value"] = propertyType(propertiesDict[field])
            def setter(field, self, value):
                s = getattr(self, f"{field}Changed")
                setattr(self, f"{field}Value", value)
                s.emit()
            def getter(field, self):
                return getattr(self, f"{field}Value")
            setterPartial = partial(setter, field)
            getterPartial = partial(getter, field)
            newDict[field] = QtCore.Property(propertyType, fset=setterPartial, fget=getterPartial, notify=s)
        return newDict

class MyObject(QtCore.QObject):
    pass

class Helper(QtCore.QObject):
    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def debugPrint(self, value):
        print(f"debugPrint {value}")

def test_proof_of_concept_dynamic_properties() -> None:
    
    print("\n")

    generatedProperties = { "foo": "FOO", "bar": 1}

    newType = types.new_class(f"MyObjectDynamic", (MyObject,), {
            "metaclass": Meta, 
            "propertiesDict": generatedProperties
            }, lambda ns: ns)
    x = newType()
    
    # x.fooValue = "foo"
    print(f"fooValue: {x.fooValue}")
    print(f"barValue: {x.barValue}")

    print(f"Foo: {x.foo}")
    print(f"Bar: {x.bar}")

    def funcFoo():
        print("funcFoo")
    def funcBar():
        print("funcBar")
    x.fooChanged.connect(funcFoo)
    x.fooChanged.connect(funcBar)
    
    x.fooChanged.emit()
    x.barChanged.emit()

    # show usage in QML
    app = QGuiApplication()

    h = Helper()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()  # type: ignore
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("myObject", x)
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("helper", h)

    engine.load("tests/main_proof_of_concept.qml")
```

main_proof_of_concept.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindows
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 500
    title: "HelloApp"

    Component.onCompleted: {
        helper.debugPrint("Completed Running!")
        helper.debugPrint("+onCompleted Foo " + myObject.foo)
        helper.debugPrint("+onCompleted Bar " + myObject.bar)
        myObject.foo = "FOO_"
        myObject.bar = 2
        helper.debugPrint("-onCompleted Foo " + myObject.foo)
        helper.debugPrint("-onCompleted Bar " + myObject.bar)
        appWindows.close()
    }
    Connections {
        target: myObject
        function onFooChanged() {
            helper.debugPrint("onResultChanged1 " + myObject.foo)
        }
    }
    Connections {
        target: myObject
        function onBarChanged() {
            helper.debugPrint("onResultChanged2 " + myObject.bar)
        }
    }

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello World "
        font.pixelSize: 24
    }

}
```

Comment: Using PySide6 I was able to reproduce this solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Re-read what return value false means](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#setProperty):

> If the property is defined in the class using Q_PROPERTY then true is
>   returned on success and false otherwise. If the property is not
>   defined using Q_PROPERTY, and therefore not listed in the meta-object,
>   it is added as a dynamic property and **false is returned**.

If you are actually having trouble using the dynamic property, then try adding relevant code to the question, such as the stylesheet you mention, and simply printing the property value after setting it.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. [QQmlPropertyMap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmlpropertymap.html):

Although this is not answering the OP directly this is probably what who came here was looking for.

example:

```py
# some_class_exposed_to_qml.py

class PageManager(qtc.QObject):
    currentPageChanged = qtc.Signal()
    A, B, C, D, E = range(5)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._current_page = self.Events
        self._pages = qqml.QQmlPropertyMap()
        self._pages.insert("A", self.A)
        self._pages.insert("B", self.B)
        self._pages.insert("C", self.C)
        self._pages.insert("D", self.D)
        self._pages.insert("E", self.E)

    @qtc.Property(qqml.QQmlPropertyMap, constant=True)
    def Pages(self):
        return self._pages
```

main.qml

```
Rectangle{id: page_A
    anchors.fill: parent;
    Text{text:"i am Page A, my value is:" + PageManager.Pages.A }
}
```

---

#### 2. [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

##### DISCLAIMER:

1. I haven't tested this so you might want to write some tests.
2. This will **ONLY** work for native data types that are supported by `QVariant` do not try to add other d.t since it wont be registered as a `QMetaType`.
3. I experienced some bugs with pycharm debugger while using this but without it it ran O.K.

##### Usage:

```py
@Qdefine # this decorator will generate 1.getter, 2.setter, 3.notify 4.property
class WinSize:
    appHeight: int
    appWidth: int
a = WinSize(400, 400)

# or dynamically create dynamic properties Xd
def make_Qdefine(name: str, bases: tuple, namespace: dict):
    return Qdefine(type(name, bases, namespace))
```

##### concept:

1. we are using [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/)(you can use dataclasses though) to initiate the underlying data
2. taking the `__annotations__` from the decorated class
3. creating an exec string that will create a class with getters setters signals and properties yada yada.
4. the `__init__` function of the class will call the `__init__` of the `attrs` class and will raise any errors given by it
5. every time you call the setter the notifier is emmitted

```py
import inspect
from attr import define
from qtpy.QtCore import *


def Qdefine(original_cls):
    """this only works for native data types"""
    attered = define(original_cls)
    exc_str = []

    for name, param in inspect.signature(attered).parameters.items():
        type_name = param.annotation.__name__
        getter = f"return self.origin.{name}"
        if param.default != inspect._empty:
            getter = param.default

        exc_str.append(
f"""    
    @Slot(result={type_name})
    def get_{name}(self):
        {getter}        
        
    @Slot({type_name})
    def set_{name}(self, value):
        self.origin.{name} = value
        self.{name}_changed.emit()
        
    @Signal
    def {name}_changed():
        pass
        
    {name} = Property({type_name}, fget=get_{name}, fset=set_{name}, notify={name}_changed)
""")

    exc_str = "\n".join(exc_str)
    exec(
f"""
class Q{original_cls.__name__}(QObject):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         self.origin = self._origin(*args, **kwargs)
         super().__init__(None)

        
{exc_str}"""
         )
    newClass = locals().get(f"Q{original_cls.__name__}")
    setattr(newClass, '_origin', attered)
    return newClass
```